# Checking if the string within the list contains portion of the string from different list twice, and return unique list after processing the list

Tags: java, string, list

`processTest` works such that if the `list` `contains` first three words or last three words or middle text from the title, it will remove from the `modifiableList`. Notice `count > 1L` -> list needs to contains similar words more than once.
I am expecting my final List to be like my test result with 3 elements but I am getting result with 4 elements. In my example test data:
Appreciate any help figuring out the issue or improving the code quality.

> 1. **not same words test 1 xyz not same words** -> shouldn't be in list, matches first three words, removed
> 2. **not difference same words test 1 xyz not not same words** -> shouldn't be in list, matches last three words, removed
> 3. **first threes words test 1 xyz not same words** -> should be in list
> 4. **first three words test 2 xyz last three words** -> shouldn't be in list, matches last three/first words
> 5. **first three words test 3 xyz last three words**
>    -> shouldn't be in list, matches last three/first words
> 6. **first three words Test 4 xyz last three words** -> should be in list
> 7. **different words Test 5 xyz last different words** -> should be in list

```
@Test
  public void processDataTest() {
    List<String> modifiableList = new ArrayList<>();
    modifiableList.add("not same words test 1 xyz not same words");
    modifiableList.add("not not same words test 1 xyz not not same words");
    modifiableList.add("not same words test 1 xyz not same words");
    modifiableList.add("first three words test 2 xyz last three words");
    modifiableList.add("first three words test 3 xyz last three words");
    modifiableList.add("first three words Test 4 xyz last three words");
    modifiableList.add("different words Test 5 xyz last different words");

    List<String> filteredList =
        new ArrayList<>(modifiableList)
            .stream()
            .filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty)
            .filter(title -> !TextUtility.isThisUnicode(title, DEVANAGARI))
            .filter(title -> !isStringDuplicateOrSimilar(modifiableList, title))
            .collect(toList());
    Assert.assertEquals(3, filteredList.size());
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(
        filteredList.toArray(),
        new String[] {
          "first threes words test 1 xyz not same words",
          "first three words Test 4 xyz last three words",
          "different words Test 5 xyz last different words"
        });
  }


  private boolean isStringDuplicateOrSimilar(List<String> list, String title) {
    String[] splitStr = title.split(StringUtils.SPACE);
    String titleSubString = extractMiddleText(title);
    System.out.println(titleSubString);
    long count = list.stream().filter(containsSimilarWords(splitStr, titleSubString)).count();
    System.out.println(count);
    return list.removeIf(t -> t.equals(title) && count > 1L);
  }
```

//check if title contains middle text or first three words of title or last three words of title

```
private static Predicate<String> containsSimilarWords(String[] splitStr, String titleSubString) {
    return title ->
        title.contains(titleSubString)
            || containsFirstThreeWords(title, splitStr)
            || containsLastThreeWords(title, splitStr);
  }

  public static boolean containsFirstThreeWords(String text, String[] words) {
    return words.length > 5
        && text.contains(words[0])
        && text.contains(words[1])
        && text.contains(words[2]);
  }

  public static boolean containsLastThreeWords(String text, String[] words) {
    int length = words.length;
    return words.length > 5
        && text.contains(words[length - 1])
        && text.contains(words[length - 2])
        && text.contains(words[length - 3]);
  }

  public static String extractMiddleText(String text) {
    int mid = text.length() / 2;
    String[] parts = {text.substring(0, mid), text.substring(mid)};
    int indexOfMidOfText2 = (parts[1].length() / 2) + parts[0].length();
    return text.substring(mid / 2, indexOfMidOfText2);
  }
```

Comment: You need to put more clarification on the conditions.  Why example #2 matches last three words, but not first three words?  Example #4 & #5 first and last three words doesn't seems to match.  Your `containsFirstThreeWords` have an index starting from 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I fixed the example 2 and containsFirstThreeWords method to have an index starting 0.

Comment: Can you explain why example #4 is rejected and example #6 is accepted?

Comment: because when comparing example 4 and 5, it’s similar to one of the strings in the modifiableList, so it will remove 4 and 5 from the modifiableList. When comparing 6 to the modifiableList, it becomes unique and doesn’t reject. So, I am using this algorithm to filter out similar tweets after getting data from Twitter API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the index is fixed and using updated example (the text in your code is not updated yet), I got only 2 passing, while example #6 is rejected.  It was because the logic for contains matches the word `three` in example #6 into the text `first threes words...` in example #3.  You can test it quickly by changing the text `threes` into `yam`.

If this is undesirable, you may be able to use regex with word boundary, or just split them and use sets to find matching words.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for clarification. After changing the `index` and after your explanation, now it's clear why #6 is rejected. Thank you so much. Let me know if this `code` can even be simplified more.